# Where is the nextcloud trusted domain php file?

Tags: files, php, webserver, nextcloud, domain-server

I have newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an old desktop.

I managed to install nextcloud server version 24. I am trying to find the trusted domain php file to add a trusted domain. Can anyone point out the path to get there, or any source of info where I can read about it? I can't find the information on the nextcloud forums.

I used to be able to find it in `/usr/local/www/nextcloud/config/config.php`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the `trusted_domains` value is still set in `/config/config.php`. Here is a sample from my file showing you the format:

```
  ...
  'secret' => 'blahblahblah',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'cloud.example.net',
    1 => 'cloud.example.org',
    2 => 'cloud.example.com',
    3 => 'cloud.local',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/files/nextcloud/data',
  ...
```